# Is possible to farm blood without killing the human, and store it for later use?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

Is possible to farm blood without killing the human?
Is it possible to store this blood for future drinking, and how long?

Is there any rules or lore book talking about it?

I'm new to WoD, so if you can provide sources allowing me to look for more details, please do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It’s possible to store blood for later use.

Page 212 of the Vampire 5E core book discusses the difficulties of using bags of blood. If it comes from the hospital and has already been processed, then it can only be consumed by vampires with the Iron Gullet Merit. If it's raw, unprocessed blood in a bag, vampires of Blood Potency 2 can drink it and gain sustenance from it. It loses its Resonance after 15 minutes.

If you're drinking from stored blood regularly, you probably have the Bagger predator type (page 176), with all the benefits and drawbacks inherent thereto, including getting the Iron Gullet merit as part of the package.

You can safely draw blood using the Medicine skill.

Comment: Thank you. So it's not possible to store blood for a long period of time, is that correct ?

Comment: @DorianTurba It can be stored in hospital conditions for a long time, but raw blood will clot and coagulate, eventually becoming unusable.

Comment: So if you want to get sustenance from processed blood bag, you should take the Iron Gullet Merit and you can drink blood processed and stored for a long time. If not precessed, the blood cannot be stored for a long time, so it's useless in a storage purpose. Am I right?

Comment: @DorianTurba Yes. Of course, the Bagger predator type gets Iron Gullet as part of the deal.

Comment: If you want real world data on storing blood, then blood for transfusions can be stored for 35 days (red blood cells): https://www.blood.co.uk/why-give-blood/demand-for-different-blood-types/   But a recent study says it is past its best after 21 days: https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/health/9908613/Blood-should-be-stored-for-three-weeks-maximum-study-finds.html

Comment: @DrBob, I failed to find the sources of the paper on the second link you provide, but I find this paper (not sure if it is the correct one but still interesting): https://www.nature.com/articles/micronano2017103

Comment: @DorianTurba  I think the correct paper is this one: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3744176/   However, if you go onto Google Scholar and search for "blood storage times" you'll find lots of papers. Google Scholar is at: https://scholar.google.co.uk/

Comment: Thank for the original paper. Yes I know Google scholar, I have used it for the first paper I found, but not yet very used to what keyword I have to use when looking for a specific paper.